# Error with library ActiveAndroid the attribut id in my model

Tags: android, overriding, activeandroid

I have a problem when I use the library 'ActiveAndroid' including the model and to be more precise with the getId method. Each time, I get the error: 
Error: (22, 17) error: getId () in Member can not override getId () in Model 
overridden method is final.

I want to use this model as well to parse my objects via retrofit for serialization in the database.

There would be no way around the problem?

my class member :

```
 public class Member extends Model {

 @Column(name = "id")
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "accessCode")
 private String accessCode;

 public void setId(int id){
      this.id=id;
 }

 public int getId(){
       return this.id;
 }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problems

```
@Column(name = "idMember")
@SerializedName(value="id")
private int idMember;
```